# .htaccess 301 redirect all pages from old domain to a specific page of new domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to 301 redirect an old domain ie :- http://olddomain.com to http://www.newdomain.com and not only i want to redirect only olddomain.com to my newdomain.com but i want to redirect any url of the olddomain.com to newdomain.com .
While i have used this code for doing this

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.newdomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

But the problem is that every url of olddomain.com is redirecting to new root domain ie "newdomain.com" for example "olddomain.com/en " is redirecting successfully to "newdomain.com" but "olddomain.com/index.php?lang=en" is redirecting to "newdomain.com/?lang=en" .

Why "olddomain.com/index.php?lang=en" is not redirecting to "newdomain.com" . How to fix it ?

Comment: Use: `RewriteRule ^ http://www.newdomain.com/? [R=301,L]` to discard any old query string.

Comment: where should i add this line of code ? or do i have to replace any line by this ?

Comment: it is working on browsers incognito tab now but it is not working on main browser . how should i check it that it is done successfully ?

Comment: Well that proves you've the right rule in place. Now fix your browser

Comment: thanks @anubhava . It worked .